# How to call a user Python function from within Vim to alter and replace visually selected text (without using Vim's Python Interface)?

Tags: python, vim

Let's say I have a two Python functions that can reverse a sentence. One function reverses the words, the other the letters. My task is to call one of these functions from within Vim to reformat and replace visually selected text, *and to it without involving Vim's Python Interface*, if that's possible.

To make things more concrete, here is the location of Python (and DLL), the location of my module, and an idea of how I'd like to call a function from within Vim:

```
C:/a/miniconda3/envs/gvim/python.exe
C:/b/reverser.py
:'<,'>!"C:/a/miniconda3/envs/gvim/python" "C:/b/reverser.py" reverse_words "one two three"
```

And here is the module itself:

```
import sys

def reverse_words(sentence):
    tovim = ' '.join(sentence.split(' ')[::-1])
    print(tovim)

def reverse_letters(sentence):
    tovim = sentence[::-1]
    print(tovim)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    function = sys.argv[1]
    sentence = sys.argv[2]               # "one two three"
    
    if function == 'reverse_words':
        reverse_words(sentence)          # "three two one"
    elif function == 'reverse_letters':
        reverse_letters(sentence)        # "eerht owt eno"
    else:
        print('oops')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the desired result is to use both `sys.stdin` and `sys.argv`.

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':

        from_vim = sys.stdin.read().rstrip('\n') # multiline visual selection
        function = sys.argv[1]                   # function to call
        sentence = sys.argv[2]                   # function argument
```

This works well, though, I am sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. make the Python code use `sys.stdin` instead of `sys.argv`,
2. and call it like so (untested):

   ```
   :'<,'>!path/to/script.py
   ```

   with Vim passing the visually selected lines to your Python script as `stdin`.

Comment: @romanl I made progress with your suggestion. I can now coax Vim into replacing my text using `sys.stdin`. But to accomplish this, I have to cut down the module to one (predetermined) function. Is there a way to pass in further arguments that let me select which function I want to call? (Apologies, I do not see how to show the updated module in answers to my own question.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough Python experience to answer that question.